# bootsrap datepicker can't select endDate on show event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Note that this is not the same as the datetimepicker.js plugin, which has a similar name and a [similar problem](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/1302">)!

While customizing datepicker behavior I see a bug? If I set the end date, I'm unable to highlight to indicate that hitting the enter button will select today's date.

Functionally it's fine, but visually it's wrong. Hitting enter, changing focus, then coming back to the control does work for some reason but that's not good enough in my case.

HTML:

```
<input id="bs_date" type="text" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-autoclose="true" />
```

Javascript:

```
var today = new Date();
$("[data-provide='datepicker']").datepicker("setEndDate", 
    new Date(today.getFullYear(), 
        today.getMonth(), 
        today.getDate())
);

$("[data-provide='datepicker']").on("show", function(e) {
    var isFirstShow = $(this).data("isFirstShow");
    console.log("is not first");

    if(isFirstShow === undefined) {
        console.log("is indeed first");

        $(this).data("isFirstShow", "yes");
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
        $(this).datepicker('update');
        $(this).removeAttr('placeholder');
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

The point of this code is to allow for a blank initial input field which auto-selects (but doesn't submit) today's date the first time the user clicks on it.

One would think that these two lines of code would do the job. They DO, unless you have an endDate set, at which point no dice:

```
$(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
$(this).datepicker('update');
```

It's not supposed to look like this:

[so wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUn7c.png)

It is supposed to look like this:

[so right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD2KQ.png)

Spending hours at work trying to fix this. Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fwiw, this seems to work.

```
var today = new Date();
$("[data-provide='datepicker']").on("show", function(e) {
    var isFirstShow = $(this).data("isFirstShow");
    console.log("is not first");

    if(isFirstShow === undefined) {
        console.log("is indeed first");

        $(this).data("isFirstShow", "yes");
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
        $("[data-provide='datepicker']").datepicker("setEndDate", 
                    new Date(today.getFullYear(), 
                today.getMonth(), 
                today.getDate())
        );
        $(this).datepicker('update');
        $(this).removeAttr('placeholder');
        $(this).val("");
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd say it's worth a lot seeing as it fixed my problem. :) Thanks.